# IE8: Using swiper as Angular Directive (Attribute) throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

right now i try to implement the [swiper](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper) plugin in my angular project, works fine except ie8 and below. 
the Error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference 
idangerous.swiper-2.2.js, line 2190 character 10
```

On the line in the plugin it replaces the `transform` with `matrix`. But it seems it couldnt find any element to swap.

**My Directive**

```
// Slider / Swiper Plugin
app.directive('swipe', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var slider = $(element).swiper(scope.$eval(attrs.swipe));
            $('.swipe__prev').on('click', function () {
                slider.swipePrev();
            });
            $('.swipe__next').on('click', function () {
                slider.swipeNext();
            });
            $(element).find('.swipe__pagi__element').on('click', function () {
                slider.swipeTo($('.swipe__pagi__element').index());
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="swiper-container swipe__container grid__item" swipe="{
        mode: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: 5000,
        wrapperClass: 'swipe__wrapper',
        slideClass: 'swipe__slide',
        slidesPerView: '3',
        createPagination: false
    }">
        <div class="swipe-wrapper swipe__wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide swipe__slide">
                <img src="../images/slider_pic_01.jpg" alt="Gewinn 1">
            </div>
            .......
            <div class="swiper-slide swipe__slide">
                <img src="../images/slider_pic_15.jpg" alt="Gewinn 15">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="swipe__prev"><i class="icon-caret-left"></i></span>
    <span class="swipe__next"><i class="icon-caret-right"></i></span>
    <div class="swipe__pagi"></div>
```

The Plugin works fine on the [Demo Page](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php) in IE8. Its build up the same as in the demo.. so i guess its angular...

Can anyone help or give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question I feel quiet stupid now. 
Easy answer. The Element i called `swipe-wrapper`, but my css file said `swipeR-wrapper`.